# Arredondamento igual ao Excel - C# (ARREDONDAR.PARA.CIMA)

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-excel, matemática, arredondamento

Estou com o seguinte problema, no Excel, utilizando o valor 2.0001983727441233 e a função `ARREDONDAR.PARA.CIMA` com 2 casas decimais, esse valor passa para 2.01.

No entanto, no meu código já tentei várias formas de obter o mesmo resultado e nada.

Já tentei:

- `Math.Round` - com várias casas decimais para testes);
- `Math.Round` - com a propriedade MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero;
- `Math.Ceilling`

E em nenhum dos casos eu consigo 2.01, apenas 2.00.

Alguém consegue me dizer como eu conseguiria o mesmo arredondamento do Excel? Ou se existe alguma biblioteca para tal? (Já fiz testes com algumas sem sucesso).

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 1):

É só usar `MidpointRounding.ToPositiveInfinity`

```cs
Math.Round(number, 2, MidpointRounding.ToPositiveInfinity)
```

[A documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding?view=net-6.0) explica bem esse parâmetro e tem vários exemplos de quando usar cada valor de `MidpointRounding`

Outra opção é calcular "na mão", provavelmente não é necessário nada muito elaborado.

```cs
Console.WriteLine(Math.Ceiling(number * 100) / 100);
```

[Veja ambos exemplos funcionando no Repl.it.](https://replit.com/@jfbueno/ptso545672)

Comment: O "ToPositiveInfinity", não é nativo. No meu Round só aparece o MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero ou MidpointRounding.ToEven.

Comment: É nativo sim. Porém não existe no .NET Framework. Eu não tinha como adivinhar qual .NET está sendo usado.

Comment: Não estou usando o .NET Core... pelo que vi o "ToPositiveInfinity" só existe no CORE. Mas muito obrigada pela ajuda. De fato eu não expliquei no post.

Comment: De qualquer forma eu vou atualizar a resposta com a solução manual.

Comment: Jéf, muito obrigada. No entanto, essa opção do Math.Ceilling não funcionaria para um número diferente, por exemplo 2,0000000000001. Como o valor é resultado de uma conta... preciso procurar algo mais padronizado... semelhante o que o Excel faz com o ARREDONDAR.PARA.CIMA.

Comment: RESOLVIDO para toda a qualquer condição:

double a = valor;
string b = a.ToString(EN);
double c = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(b.Substring(0, b.IndexOf(".") + 3), EN) + (Convert.ToInt64(b.Substring(b.IndexOf(".") + 3)) > 0 ? 0.01 : 0), 2);

Testado e funcionando!

Comment: @LisaGuedes Tem que funcionar. Qual o resultado com `2,0000000000001`? Tratar números como string - ainda mais pra uma operação naturalmente matemática é geralmente uma má ideia.